# jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin check wheather empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have downloaded JQuery Multiple file uploader from this site

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

I need to check whether the file input field  is null or not before submitting the form.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="save" />
</form>
```

I tried

```
function validate() {
  $(".multi").each(function () {
    var multi =  $(this).val();
    if (multi) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Not working because the filed is always empty. So is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var multi = $(".multi").val();
    if (multi) {
        console.log("multi");
    } else {
        console.log("no multi");
    }
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w4qVv/

**UPDATE:**

or you can do it like this

```
function validate(field) {
    var fieldVal = $(field).val();
      if(!fieldVal)   alert("No files selected");

}
```

and then:

```
 validate(".multi");
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jk8aZ/

**UPDATE2:**

yep, you can use each like this

```
var multi = (".multi");
    $(multi).each(function () {
        validate(this);
    });
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jk8aZ/1/

Comment: What about if I am having multiple upload file with the same class name.?

Comment: can you please check this link http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ Its always empty if there is a file or not that was the issue..